# How can a trigger automatically fired after 5 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I got a `Shoppping List` table with columns such as:

```
shopID, Product, DateTimeShopped, PaiedOrNot, ListStatus
```

My requirement is comparing the current datetime with `DateTimeShopped`, if the shopping list is still not paid after 5 days, then automatically label the `ListStatus` to be `Blocked`.

How can I handle the time issue in within a trigger in SQL Server?

Thanks.

Comment: you can schedule a SQL Server Agent job daily and run your sp.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: In theory you could use `EXEC sp_add_schedule` to set up a single run agent job to run at a specified date, although personally I would look for another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a SP `ShoppingListSP`

```
declare @current datetime    
set @current = (select GETDATE() )

if ( datediff(@DateTimeShopped,@current ) > 5)
begin
    update [Shopping List] set ListStatus = 'Blocked' where id=123123
end
```

then create a SQL job which runs this SP every hour or so in the background.

```
exec ShoppingListSP
```

you might need use Cursors as well to work on a set of data, row by row.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**. You can't.

**Long answer**. It is possible to run more than a simple statement from a trigger, however, this would not be the best place for it.

**Another Option**. I would insert the data into another table and run a stored proc from Sql Agent to action it accordingly.